# fs.readFileSync returning weird encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use `readFileSync` to copy the contents of a Javascript file and then place it into an HTML file. However when I do so the outputted code is getting encoded and causing errors when the JS runs. For example `=` is getting encoded into `&#x3D;`.

I've used different variations for the encoding like so 
`fs.readFileSync('dist/' + v + '.min.js')`
`fs.readFileSync('dist/' + v + '.min.js', 'utf8')`

and the output doesn't change.

I'm using Webpack and the HtmlWebpackPlugin to read the file and serve it to a Handlebars template. When I log out the contents of the file it looks correct, so it's looking like Handlebars is mashing up the text for some reason.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are adding the code to the HTML file?

Comment: Is `=` represented as `&#x3D` after reading (if you log the content to console) or after you added it to your html? And if it happens after adding it to html, then show how you do that.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm using the HtmlWebpackPlugin with the inline option. Will update above